# Cannot paste from clipboard in KDE on first try

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

Ever since I upgraded to Fedora 32 pasting does not work properly in KDE.  It copies correctly what I want to be copied, but it will not paste right away.  I either have to go to the clipboard applet in the tray and click on the item and then paste it where I want or copy the item that I want twice.  I have "Save clipboard contents on exit", "Prevent empty clipboard" and "Ignore images" disabled.  I only have "Ignore selection" enabled.  The timeout for action popups are: 8 seconds and the clipboard history size is: 1 entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Prevent empty clipboard" must be enabled. See [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/copy-paste-problem-works-every-other-time/36957/22)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1195101)